# How to clone a form and make the clone function exactly as the original?

Tags: forms, clone

I have the following form:

```
    $(function() {
$("#message").keyup(function() {
var text_msg = $("#message").val();
    if(text_msg.length > 3 && text_msg.length <= 140)
    {
        $('#post').attr('disabled', '');
        $('#post').attr('value', 'Submit');
    }else{
        $('#post').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        $('#post').attr('value', 'Wait...')
        if(text_msg.length > 3 && text_msg.length > 140){
            alert('Your message exceeded the number of characters which is 140. Delete a few letters.');
        }
    }

});
```

});

```
        $(function() {
$(".resp").click(function(){
    var idf = $(this).attr('id');   
    newform = $("form#form-msg").clone(true);
        $("#new-form-"+idf).append(newform);// These id's are generated dynamically
    });
 });

    <form method="post" name="form-msg" id="form-msg" action="javascript:func()"> 
        <textarea id="message" name="message"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="wait..." id="post" align="left" disabled="disabled" />
    </form>

<div id="new-form-1"></div>
<div class="resp" align="center" id="1">Reply</div>
<div id="new-form-2"></div>
<div class="resp" align="center" id="2">Reply</div>
<div id="new-form-3"></div>
<div class="resp" align="center" id="3">Reply</div>
```

When I'm cloning the form it does not work like the original, the submit button is not active, not in a State to submit the form. Everything works perfectly, less inputs of cloned form. How do I make a clone function equal to the original?

Answer (score 0):

you need to remove the attribute instead of just blanking them, the existence of disabled attribute, even if it's empty will cause the button to be disabled. With jQuery, this means `$(...).removeAttr('disabled')` as opposed to `$(...).attr('disabled', '')`

Comment: There was an error in other JQ code, fix this error but I realized that I can't get the value entered in the field.